# Create lists with 3 levels, containing every combination of sub list(s) values

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, list, numpy, python-itertools

I am currently stuck with the following problem (I could not find solution already on here that really fitted this):

I have three lists `a = [a, b, c]`, `b = [1, 2, 3]` and `c = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]`.

I would like to create a lists of list of lists (maybe I should be using numpy arrays?), that contains all combinations between these lists, but where each element in each sub list are also iterated in a bruce-force like pattern, such that the following is generated:

`mylist = [[[a, 1, 0.1], [b, 1, 0.1], [c, 1, 0.1]],
 [[a, 1, 0.1], [b, 1, 0.1], [c, 1, 0.2]],
 ...
 [[a, 2, 0.3], [b, 3, 0.3], [c, 1, 0.1]],
 ...
 [[a, 1, 0.3], [b, 1, 0.3], [c, 1, 0.3]],
 ...
 [[a, 3, 0.3], [b, 1, 0.3], [c, 3, 0.1]]
 ...
 [[a, 3, 0.3], [b, 3, 0.3], [c, 3, 0.3]]]`

I appreciate that this would equate to an extremely large list (happy to be advised on a better approach!), but I effectively need to have a three dimensional list with each sublist e.g. mylist[0],  passed as list containing individual sublist parameters (e.g., [[a, 3, 0.3], [b, 3, 0.3], [c, 3, 0.3]] to an algorithm which will use them as input. This 3-D list forms effectively the entire parameter space that will need to be "searched". Thus you can see why the following combination examples:

`[[a, 1, 0.3], [b, 2, 0.3], [c, 2, 0.3]],
[[a, 3, 0.1], [b, 1, 0.3], [c, 2, 0.1]]`

Are important, because they serve as a unique of parameters for algorithmic input.

Really grateful for any guidance on this, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So, what have you tried?

Comment: what is the output dimension?

Comment: @kevinkayaks, the output dimensions are as follows:

Comment: ` x = [[[a],[0],[0.1]],[[a],[0],[0.1]],[[a],[0],[0.1]]], y = all combinations of above`. Does that make sense? So 3 dimensions, where y equals all the combinations for a row as described above.

Comment: @Andreas I had try to have recursive loops for each list, then using iterools with permutations, but could not get the right output as per above.

Comment: Then include your attempt in the question instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generator seems a good approach, to avoid cluttering up the memory.

```
import itertools as it
bc=list(it.product(b,c)) 
#[(1, 0.1), (1, 0.2), (1, 0.3), (2, 0.1), (2, 0.2), (2, 0.3), (3, 0.1), (3, 0.2), (3, 0.3)]
res = ([[u,*v] for u,v in zip(a,bc3)] for bc3 in it.product(*[bc]*3))
```

you can then scan your space with :

```
 for list_of_list in res : 
    #compute  list_of_list
```

First values :

```
In [49]: next(res) 
Out[49]: [['a', 1, 0.1], ['b', 1, 0.1], ['c', 1, 0.1]] 
In [50]: next(res) 
Out[50]: [['a', 1, 0.1], ['b', 1, 0.1], ['c', 1, 0.2]]
```

You can obtain an array by `arr  = np.array(list(res),dtype=object)` . its shape is (729,3,3).

Comment: @Ryan this is the best answer. Thanks B.M., I learned from this.

Comment: @kevinkayaks terms of stackoverflow etiquette is it acceptable to change the answer to this if it is better than a previously posted answer?

Comment: @B. M. That works perfectly, and much more elegant. Thank you.

Comment: @Ryan people do this. It's not a huge deal as far as I know. Presumably it will help people who are searching for an approach in the future to select the best one.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np 
import itertools as it
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
l = np.array(np.meshgrid(a,b,c)).T
l = l.reshape(l.size//3,3)
subs = [[list(x) for x in l if x[0]==val] for val in a]
list(list(x) for x in it.product(*subs))
```

Try this one. It generalizes to `a,b,c,d,...` in an obvious way.

That said, you're going to run out of memory very quickly.

Comment: I don't think this exactly what I am looking for. For example, each X ("row") dimension should consist of the following: `[[a, 1, 0.1],[b, 1, 0.1][c, 1, 0.2]]`, with all subsequent rows containing all of combinations in an iterative way for each sublist. Such that `list = [[[],[],[]],[[[],[],[]]]` and each sublist iterates through every combination possible between the possible values in list b and c. In the output, each row should consist of these combinations for values a, b, c in list a. I hope I haven't been too confusing!

Comment: Yes I tried `itertools.combinations` and `itertools.permutations`, thanks for the above. Yes, memory is a problem, although for the time being I am ignoring this problem for the sake of experimentation. As @Red Cricket answered first (and I didn't ask explicitly for the most elegant solution), I have to accept his answer, but will upvote this one (it will accept my vote, but not post it visibly because of my uber newbie status). Thanks again.

Comment: For context regarding the memory problem. This list is to generate an action space containing combinations of parameters for reinforcement learning. So, ideally in the case of millions of combination as a, b, c, d etc., scales the RL environment would obviously need lots of memory,.